# How to create a function that loops through both the key and item of a dictionary using variables in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary:

```
d1 = {'a': [2, 10], 'b': [-4, 5.5]}
```

I want to write a function that prints this:

```
table 1 2 10
table 2 -4 5.5
```

The following works, but there is a problem because it is not universal enough for my needs:

```
def f1(x):
    for i in x: 
        print('table ',i,x[i][0],x[i][1])
f1(d1)
```

Output:

```
table 1 2 10
table 2 -4 5.5   # worked!! But not universal :(
```

The problem is that in the print line, the 0 and 1 have to be inserted manually.

I am trying to make the function more universal, meaning it should be able to handle more than two keys. So a ‘c’ could be in the dictionary from the beginning with another list of numbers associated with it for example.
And I want the function to handle more than just two items in each list, so 2,10 for key ‘a’ could instead be 2,10,15,14 from the beginning for example.

So, if I could make the 0 and 1 in the print line a variable that would be great, if I use something like `x[i][j]`, where j is coming from a another loop or some where that is keeping track of the index value of the items in the lists in the dictionary.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `dict.iteritems()` or `dict.items()` to gain access to both the keys and values simultaneously...

Comment: How did you come up with `table 1`, table `2`, and not `table a`, `table b`? Are you aware that dictionaries are inherently unordered? With hash randomisation enabled each code run will have different iteration ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Try this:

```
for i, k in enumerate(sorted(d1.keys()), 1):
    print('table', i,  *d1[k])
```

Output:

```
table 1 2 10
table 2 -4 5.5
```

## In Steps

Dictionaries are not ordered. So sorting the keys with `sorted(d1.keys())` provides a consistent order of the printed rows. You can use `enumerate(iterable, 1)` to start counting with `1`. Here `i` will hold this number. `d1[k]` gives you the value, i.e.each list in your dictionary. The `*` in `*d1[k]` will unpack the entries from the list in the `print()` function. This has the same effect as writing:

```
print('table', i,  d1[0], d1[1])
```

where the index inside the `[]` will go from `0` to `len(d1) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
d = {'a': [2, 10], 'b': [-4, 5.5]}

for i, k in enumerate(d):
    print (i + 1), d[k]
```

After you can adjust but `enumerate` is clearly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach (python 2.7):

```
d1={'a': [2, 10], 'b': [-4, 5.5]}
def f1(x):
    for i, v in enumerate(x.values()): 
        print  'table', i+1, ' '.join( map(str, v)) 
f1(d1)
```

Output:

```
table 1 2 10
table 2 -4 5.5
```